# Разделение слова на буквы

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разделить слово на буквы и узнать их ASCII код? Знаю только, что ASCII код буквы можно узнать путем перевода его в `int`. Но как будет в данном случае?

Comment: @navi1893, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **Не нужно** преобразовывать `string` в `char *`
2. В цикле проходим от 0 до конца строки (до `s.size()-1`)
3. Каждый символ строки получаем через `s[i]`, преобразовываем в `int` и выводим.

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {    
       string s = "This is a text";
       for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
           cout << (int)s[i] << endl;
       return 0; 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно

1. Преобразовать `string` в `char *`
2. В цикле пройтись до конца строки `'\0'`
3. Перевести char в int и вывести для каждого элемента строки

-

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string from = "This is a text";
    char *to = (char *) from.c_str();

    while (*to++ != '\0') {
        cout << (int) *to << endl;
    }    
}
```